# Rails Geocoder custom order result other than distance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am using Geocoder (https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) to find near by stores like this:
Store.near([@lat, @long], 20)
is there a way to sort my results by id instead distance?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by pass order: false in near method

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `reorder` instead of `order` to apply any sort order on `near` results:
`Store.near([@lat, @long], 20).reorder(:id)`

The `reorder` replaces the `order` statement created by the previous scopes.